# Selecting top-categories if sub-categories have data

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I basically have a table **hebergement_type** with the following data:

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗   
║     category     ║   sub_category   ║      label       ║ hebergement_count ║   
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣   
║ main             ║                  ║ Immo             ║                 5 ║   
║ main             ║                  ║ Hotel            ║                 5 ║   
║ main             ║ chambre-vacances ║ Appart + Studios ║                   ║   
║ chambre-vacances ║                  ║ Appart Vacances  ║                 2 ║   
║ chambre-vacances ║                  ║ Studios          ║                 3 ║   
╚══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Returns immo, hotel:

```
SELECT hebergement_type.label hebergement_type.id FROM hebergement
JOIN hebergement_type ON hebergement.hebergement_type = hebergement_type.id
WHERE hebergement_type.category = 'main'
```

Returns immo, hotel, appart vacances, studios:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hebergement_type.label, hebergement_type.id FROM hebergement
JOIN hebergement_type ON hebergement.hebergement_type = hebergement_type.id
LEFT JOIN hebergement_type as ht ON ht.sub_category = hebergement_type.category
WHERE ht.category = 'main' OR hebergement_type.category = 'main'
```

However we need to return: immo, hotel, appart+studios -> as in return all categories that match 'main' type that are not empty AND in case where there is sub_category, check sub_category items.

**DDL for hebergement**

```
CREATE TABLE hebergement (id INTEGER NOT NULL, hebergement_type INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, name VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id), CONSTRAINT FK_4852DD9C46ABB3B4 FOREIGN KEY (hebergement_type) REFERENCES hebergement_type (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE);
```

**DDL for hebergement_type**

```
CREATE TABLE hebergement_type (id INTEGER NOT NULL, category VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, sub_category VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, label VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

I added hebergement_count just to say that there are 5 immo, 5 hotels, 2 appart vacances, 3 studios etc.

**NOTE:**
I need to get the query to work in a doctrine2 repository...

Comment: Hmm how did you get the table to work? Thanks @mah

Comment: DDL for the table might help a little.

Comment: @dan2k3k4 I added 4 spaces to the beginning of each of its lines. Initially I tried enclosing the full table within backticks but that didn't quite work as expected.

Comment: Added DDL @ChrisFarmer